# Как передать свойство в наследуемый класс?

Tags: javascript

Как передать свойство (массив `visitinMagazine` уже заполненный `true` `false`) в `class Calculation` метод `amountOfVisits` ?

```js
class Student {
    constructor(firstName,lastName,yearOfBirth,arrayOfGrades) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
        this.arrayOfGrades = arrayOfGrades;
    }
    //______Возраст студента______//
    getAge () {
        return console.log(`${this.firstName}'s old is ${2023 - this.yearOfBirth} years`);
    }
    //______Средний бал______//
    averageMark () {
        let sum = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.arrayOfGrades.length; i++) {
            sum = sum + this.arrayOfGrades[i];
        }
        return console.log(`${this.firstName}'s average mark is ${sum / this.arrayOfGrades.length}`);
    }

}
//______Экземпляры студентов______//
const student = new Student('Dmitriy','Yaroshchuk',2001,[70,80,90,100,90,90,99,100,95,100]);
const student1 = new Student('Andrew','Kavetsky',2000,[90,90,90,90,90,90,100,100,95,93]);
const student2 = new Student('Diana','Koko',1999,[70,70,70,70,70,70,75,75,75,93]);



//______Вызываю методы______//
student.getAge();
student1.getAge();
student2.getAge();
student.averageMark();
student1.averageMark();
student2.averageMark();

class Visit extends Student {
    constructor(firstName, lastName, yearOfBirth, arrayOfGrades) {
        super(firstName, lastName, yearOfBirth, arrayOfGrades);
        this.visitinMagazine = [];
    }
    //______Используется когда студент был на занятие______//
    present () {
        if (this.visitinMagazine.length < 26) {
            this.visitinMagazine.push(true);
            return this;
        } else {
            return this.visitinMagazine.pop();
        }
    }
    //______Используется когда студент НЕ был на занятие______//
    absent () {
        if (this.visitinMagazine.length < 26) {
            this.visitinMagazine.push(false);
            return this;
        } else {
            return this.visitinMagazine.pop();
        }
    }
}

//______Экземпляры посейщения______//
const visit = new Visit('Dmitriy', 'Yaroshchuk', 2001, [70, 80, 90, 100, 90, 90, 99, 100, 95, 100])
const visit1 = new Visit('Andrew', 'Kavetsky', 2000, [90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 100, 100, 95, 93])
const visit2 = new Visit('Diana', 'Koko', 1999, [70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 75, 75, 75, 93])

//______Посейщение уроков______//
visit.present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().absent().absent();
const callOfVisitnMagazine = [...visit.visitinMagazine];
// console.log(callOfVisitnMagazine);

//______Посейщение уроков______//
visit1.absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().absent().present().present();
const callOfVisitnMagazine1 = [...visit1.visitinMagazine];
// console.log(callOfVisitnMagazine1);

//______Посейщение уроков______//
visit2.present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().present().absent().absent().absent();
const callOfVisitnMagazine2 = [...(visit2.visitinMagazine)];
// console.log(callOfVisitnMagazine2);


 class Calculation extends Visit {
    constructor(firstName, lastName, yearsOfBirth, arrayOfGrades) {
        super(firstName, lastName, yearsOfBirth, arrayOfGrades);
    }
     //______Колличество занятий______//
     amountOfClasses () {
         return console.log(this.arrayOfGrades.length);
     }
     //______Колличество посищений______//
     amountOfVisits () {
         return console.log(this.callOfVisitnMagazine.filter((element) => element === true).length);
     }
     //______Проверяем среднюю оценку и посейщение______//
     summary () {
         const averageVisit = this.amountOfVisits / this.amountOfClasses;
         if (this.averageMark > 90 && averageVisit > 0.9) {
             return console.log('Cool!');
         } else if (this.averageMark > 90 || averageVisit > 0.9) {
             return console.log('Good, but it can be better!');
         } else {
             return console.log('Radish');
         }
     }
 }
//______Экземпляры расчетов______//
const calculate = new Calculation('Dmitriy', 'Yaroshchuk', 2001, [70, 80, 90, 100, 90, 90, 99, 100, 95, 100])
const calculate1 = new Calculation('Andrew', 'Kavetsky', 2000, [90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 100, 100, 95, 93])
const calculate2 = new Calculation('Diana', 'Koko', 1999, [70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 75, 75, 75, 93])

calculate.amountOfClasses();
calculate1.amountOfClasses();
calculate2.amountOfClasses();

calculate.amountOfVisits(callOfVisitnMagazine);
calculate1.amountOfVisits(callOfVisitnMagazine1);
calculate2.amountOfVisits(callOfVisitnMagazine2);

calculate.summary();
calculate1.summary();
calculate2.summary();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш метод должен принимать этот массив:

```
amountOfVisits (vizitMagaz) {
    console.log(vizitMagaz.filter((element) => element === true).length);
}
```

Когда вы обращаетесь к this, вы обращаетесь к свойствам и методам класса.

UPD: 
Вы немного перемудрили :) 
Вам не нужна внешняя переменная(если конечно вы не планируете делать что то магическое с ней). У вас же есть эти данные в классе в свойстве **visitinMagazine**. Можно сделать так и рузультат будет таким же:

```
amountOfVisits () {
    console.log( this.visitinMagazine.filter((element) => element === true).length);
}
```

З.Ы.: Что в первом, что во втором случае, делать `return console.log()` бессмысленно